# Expected value of a random variable with truncation

Tags: probability, expected-value, truncation, partial-moments

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R_+$ denote the PDF of a random variable $X$ and $c>0$ a constant. I want to evaluate the following integral:
$$I(c)=\int_0^\infty{\min(x,c)f(x)dx}.$$
This can be written as
$$I(c)=\int_0^c{x \cdot f(x) dx} + \int_c^\infty{c \cdot f(x) dx} = \int_0^c{x \cdot f(x) dx} + c\cdot\mathrm{Pr}(x>c).$$
I'm wondering whether the first term is an expected value on a truncated support or something like this.

Comment: You don't have $f$ anywhere in your integrals...

Comment: See "partial expectation".  We have [a handful of useful references to it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22partial+expectation%22) here on CV.  As far as *evaluating* the integral goes, in what terms do you want it?  For instance, the integral of $xf(x)$ from $0$ to $c$ can be expressed as an integral of the CCDF $1-F$ over the same region, but would you consider that to be an "evaluation"?

Comment: @jbowman sorry, I somehow missed it.

Comment: @whuber I was thinking whether it has a "nice" Interpretation like a conditional expected value, like $\mathbb E(X \mid x \in [0,c])$ (I don't know if that is actually a stats concept). The second term nicely unfolds to a probability yielding an easy to understand layman interpretation. 

Btw: what does the second C stand for in CCDF?

Comment: @whuber yes, I was looking for partial expectation $\mathbb E(X \mid X \in (0,K])\cdot\mathrm{Pr}(X \in (0,K])$. Thanks.